# Can I paramentrize a typedef struct in System Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In order to optimize design, I want to make a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
  logic a1;
  logic a2;

  generate if (CFG_B) begin
    logic b1; 
    logic b2;
  end endgenerate
} my_struct
```

or I also tried:

```
generate if (CFG_A) begin 
  typedef struct {
  < a1, a2>
  } my_struct
end endgenerate

generate if (CFG_B) begin 
  typedef struct {
  < a1, a2, b1, b2>
  } my_struct
end endgenerate
```

I want to have structure with fields `[a1, a2]` in CFG_A; `[a1, a2, b1, b2]` in CFG_B.

Showed code doesn't work (this was predictable..), I have no more ideas how to describe this struct.

Comment: did you try the compiler directive if either of the CFG active throughout the simulation?

Comment: Sorry, I made it not clear, there is a parameter "CFG" and its value sets "CFG_A" (mb when CFG = 0) or "CFG_B" (CFG = 1), shown code is simplified (yea.. my fault)

Comment: no, there is no such way. Your best bet would be to pass a corresponding structure as a type to a parameterized module.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example which illustrates my comment above. You can use parameterized modules to do something like you talked about, if you can organize your code in such a way.

1. have all versions of your struct deined
2. Instantiate parameterized modules in a generate block.
3. pass the type of the struct based on the generated instance
4. make sure that you use it correctly in the module, using generate blocks there.

This would only work with system verilog.

```
typedef struct {
  logic a, b;
} A;

typedef struct {
  logic a, b, c, d;
} B;

parameter CFG = 1;

module top();

  if (CFG)
    mod#(.S(A)) m();
  else
    mod#(.S(B)) m();
endmodule

module mod#(type S = A) ();
  S s;
  always_comb 
    s.a = s.b;
  
  if (!CFG) begin
    always_comb
        s.c = s.d;   
  end

endmodule
```